# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'N', when I want to plot my data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, matplotlib

I read an excel file and store it an pandas:

```
        dataframe= pd.read_excel(
            self.INPUT_FILE,
            sheet_name="output",
            skiprows=1,
            index_col="times",
            nrows=1500,
        )
```

later, I want to plot it:

```
   from tigramite import plotting as tp

        tp.plot_scatterplots(
            name="plot_scatterplots",
            dataframe=self.dataframe,
            add_scatterplot_args={"matrix_lags": matrix_lags},
        )
```

And I have this error:

**'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'N'**

It is a kind of "fix" for this problem if I add this line before plotting:

```
        self.dataframe = pp.DataFrame(self.dataframe.to_numpy())
```

But I don't understand why it works.

Nevertheless, according this, I thought this should work:

```
        tp.plot_scatterplots(
            name="plot_scatterplots",
            dataframe=self.dataframe.to_numpy(),
            add_scatterplot_args={"matrix_lags": matrix_lags},
        )
```

But in this case, I have this error message:

**'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'N'**

I printed the header and there are no spaces in that, I also have another dataset in CSV format and I have the same error there too. The print of the head is this:

```
<bound method NDFrame.head of        engine_temperatures  motor_p0_speeds  engine_powers_out  co2_emissions  fuel_consumptions_liters_value
times
0                25.000000      2477.816545           0.075606       0.557940                        0.000000
1                25.046077      2477.816545           0.075606       0.557563                        0.000212
```

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: A quick web seach on `tigramite` shows that `N` is an attribute, number of variables.  This package is not in your list of tags, and few of us, if any,  know about this.  You are responsible for following the documentation of any such package that you import.